# Reasons someone might build a giant ring around a planet?

Tags: megastructures

And to immediately clarify that title, no I do not mean an orbital ring. That has an obvious use. The artifact I'm imagining is more like a giant fiber-optic cable (though it need not necessarily serve that purpose) wrapped dozens of times around the circumference of the Earth like a yarn-ball. This enormous cable would be found miles underground by the very confused humans who discovered it, who were expecting to find such a structure miles above ground a la an orbital ring.

What is it? Why is it there? Who built it and what did they intend to use it for? I've gotten so far as imagining this giant ring/cable wrapped around the Earth, but I haven't got a clue how to answer these questions yet. And while I imagine the point of writing a short-story about this thing would be accomplishing more by exploring people's reactions to these questions rather than their actual answers, I feel like I myself should at least have a good idea before I decide to invest any more time into fleshing this idea out.

Does anyone have any ideas that might give me a place to start?

Comment: This question seems really, really broad, but I'm not sure how you could narrow it down. It's basically asking for any ideas.

Comment: It has a linear motor in it, it's used for launching deep space craft without burning a ton of rocket fuel to do so.  Launch a corresponding counterweight at the same time and the ring remains stable.  Note, however, that such a ring is inherently unstable and will like to fall out of orbit.  (See Larry Niven, *The Ringworld Engineers* for a discussion of this, or even just Google about it.)

Answer (score 2):

I reckon just that, as a giant fiber optic cable that your people end up adopting for themselves. Perhapse it was placed there by a precursor race that either went with the dinosaurs or emigrated due to inhospitable conditions (or boredom?). They used it as a form of extremely fast data highway and directed loads of information through it; like an internet. This creates a bit of conflict because there are alien data stores still left on their network and since the cable is worldwide countries are trying to drill down and access it and delete it before other countries can get to it.

Or perhapse the sun was emitting particularly powerful solar waves that were overwhelming earth's magnetic field and slowly cooking Earth, so they set down the rings (and charged it with an energy source?) to bolster the magnetic field, but couldn't set-it-up in time and were roasted (with the dinosaurs?). This creates a motivation to pick-up where the precursors left off because the solar rays are going to rev up again.

Best of luck.

Comment: [My answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/265865/76902) for energy required in superconducting ring for solar-wind protection could be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

An absolutely huge antenna or electromagnet for sending a strong signal into deep space, maybe as a navigation buoy.

A super huge RF tag for passive identification.

Either of the above used as a boundary marker for a division of space territory between alien adversaries.